# How to convert MBR disk to GPT disk on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, formatting, mbr, gpt

My new harddrive is larger than 2TB, and for some reasons I have to convert it to GPT disk so I can use all the space.

How can I convert my WD Red 3TB into GPT disk so I can use all its capacity?

I tried the commandline feature (diskpart), but it said it cannot convert it to GPT format.

I am using Windows XP SP3 32bit.

Comment: @EliadTech, So i have to install Windows 7 ? Will 32bit version do it too? (i dont like to risk installing 64bit since i have found them to be very unstable).

Comment: Yes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Windows:_32-bit_versions
As for your strange notion about instability of 64-bit systems, I've been using one for four years now, and haven't seen anything out of the ordinary.
Maybe you have some bad taste left from XP 64-bit?

Comment: @EliadTech, i installed 64bit windows 7 on a laptop once, and almost every program crashed every now and then. I have enough problems by installing 32bit windows 7, why risk with 64bit? It already takes 12 hours to set up a windows install to its final stage.

Comment: Don't let one bad experience to break you...
Anyhow, what programs are running exactly?
If you run some legacy programs than that could be a problem.
Also, why do need the 3TB drive? does your (legacy?) programs require access to this drive?
If you wish to stay with XP32b, you might want to try this:
http://www.ghacks.net/2010/11/04/how-to-use-3tb-hard-drives-on-windows-xp/

Comment: @EliadTech, i dont need 3TB drive, but i already bought it. i could have just bought 2x 2TB drives yeah. now i have already installed windows 7. this is slower, but geh, i guess i need to buy better GFX card now too. i dont remember exactly what programs crashed on that laptop, but it was unstable as hell. even just listening to music via winamp made it crash if you did something else at same time. installing 32bit windows 7 fixed those crashes instantly.